# Rails DateTime re-format using #{DateTime.now}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, amazon-s3, strftime

I have a task in Rails that exports an xml, I've one line in it though

```
tmp_filename="#{Rails.root}/tmp/orders-#{o.id}-#{DateTime.now}.xml"
```

and this outputs the xml file with a filename like

```
orders-42-2015-01-28T17:22:35+00-00.xml
```

This is the way it shows up when its uploaded directly to amazon s3, the problem is I need to get rid of the colons and just have dashes because the system thats taking these files doesn't work properly with the colon in the filename.

The strange thing is that when I download the file from s3 it downloads as dashes.
I'm not sure how or if I can use strftime on #{}
Could anybody help with what I'm trying to do. Or if this is just an amazon s3 thing and the file is actually being generated with the - and not : already.

Strftime doesn't seem to work on amazon s3, the file still uploads as the original format even after adding

```
tmp_filename="#{Rails.root}/tmp/orders-#{o.id}-#{DateTime.now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H%M%S')}.xml"
```

and it also adds an extra +00:00 at the end for some reason that I can't get rid of

Comment: Use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method (`DataTime.now.strftime(format)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just format the DateTime without colons, for example:

```
tmp_filename="#{Rails.root}/tmp/orders-#{o.id}-#{DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}.xml"
```

With this you'll get the time in format like below, without colons:

```
irb(main):010:0> DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
=> "2015-01-29-10-50-30"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I added that in but the file is still showing up with colons for the time on s3, it must just be a amazon thing